# C# on Linux - Required framework not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, archlinux

**Background**

I have installed the .NET framework on Arch GNU/Linux following the [ArchWiki guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/.NET).

The main packages were:

- `dotnet-runtime` to run .NET managed applications
- `dotnet-sdk` to build apps with .NET

Furthermore, I added `~/.dotnet/tools` to `PATH` so that I can use dotnet tools from shell. I've done so by adding

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/MyUserName/.dotnet/tools"
```

to my `~/.zshenv` file.

---

**Problem**

Everything worked fine, and I was able to build a few console apps. However, when I tried to build an ASP.NET Core Web App, I encountered some problems.

First, I created a new Web App by running:

```
dotnet new webapp -n MyAppsName --framework net6.0
```

When I try to build and run, I get the following error:

```
Building...
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /home/MyUserName/RestOfThePath/MyAppsName/bin/Debug/net6.0/MyAppsName
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=arch-x64
```

It seems that the framework (or the appropriate version) is missing. However, when I run `dotnet --info`, it does not seem that anything I need is missing. Below is the output of the previous command.

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.109
 Commit:    58a93139d8

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     arch
 OS Version:
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.109/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.9
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       163a63591c

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.109 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

---

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-discovery/troubleshoot-app-launch?pivots=os-linux#net-installation-not-found) is the official Microsoft's article intended to help troubleshoot this particular issue. It did not provide any new insight.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, I saw the message. That takes you to the "Download .NET 6.0 Runtime" webpage. If you are to follow the instructions, you will eventually get to the point where it will guide you to download the official Arch Linux package 'dotnet-runtime'. As I have mentioned, I have that installed on my system.

Comment: I see. Sadly Arch is only community supported so Microsoft Docs can be badly organized for it. You can get started from the shell script https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install The answer below offers an alternative you can also try out. It is highly recommended that you use a more mainstream Linux distro for development and then deploy to Arch.

Comment: "more mainstream Linux distro" oh boy that's a hot take : )

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for trying to help. And yes (again), I saw that Microsoft offered an option for me to download a tarball and install it manually. However, I consider that against Linux philosophy as I want my package manager to do as much work for me. Hence, I did not want to consider that as an option given that Microsoft claimed that they  have official packages for Arch Linux. Now, given that I am entering the world of development as a junior and coming from C and Java, I'll accept some responsibility for not knowing how .NET is distributed.

Comment: @LexLi However, I am disappointed that the documentation was bad on both Microsoft's website and Arch Wiki (which is surprising since it is usually phenomenal). It could be perhaps the fact that C# on Linux is relatively new thing so there is not a lot of eyes on the Wiki in regards to .NET.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah lol. I guess it's not as mainstream as a Debian branch of distros, but I would not pick those words.

Comment: I edited the ArchWiki. Now, this part is documented.

Comment: "I consider that against Linux philosophy as I want my package manager to do as much work for me" is kind of funny, because when I started to learn Linux, the philosophy was completely different. "Microsoft claimed that they have official packages for Arch Linux" is also false. It's management of each distros that packs up .NET bits as official packages in the archive, not Microsoft. "Microsoft collaborates with partners to ensure .NET works well on their Linux distributions. Support is provided by those distributions" says clearly the attitude.  Microsoft only covers 6 mainstream ones.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#official-package-archives The statements are out there and each sentence is important.

Comment: @gunr2171 Microsoft is running the Azure business, so it knows much better which distributions are mainstream for itself, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#microsoft-packages no matter how you feel about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.Net (note, as of .Net 5 it's just called ".Net", not ".Net Core" or ".Net Framework") is distributed in *three* different packages.

The one you're missing is [`aspnet-runtime`](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/aspnet-runtime/).

`dotnet-sdk` lets you compile source code. `dotnet-runtime` lets you run *basic* applications. `aspnet-runtime` comes with a lot of extra stuff specific for ASP.Net, so it's distributed separately.

NORMALLY (such as on Windows), when you install the .Net Sdk, it also installs the ASP.Net runtime. It seems that on Arch the [SDK package](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/dotnet-sdk/) doesn't depend on `aspnet-runtime`.

Once you install the `aspnet-runtime` and run `dotnet --info` again, you'll see under the ".NET runtimes installed" section an entry for "Microsoft.NETCore.App" (what `dotnet-runtime` provides) and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (what `aspnet-runtime` provides).

Comment: Right to the point. Installing the missing package solved the issue. Thank you for the help as well as for explaining how .NET is distributed.

Comment: While we are on the topic, are there any other packages pertaining to the framework that I should be aware of for the future use?

Comment: Not that I know of. There may be others in the future, who knows.